Installing Jupyter Notebook on Ubuntu
ramani@ramani:~$ pip3 install jupyter
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.
    
    See /usr/share/doc/python3.12/README.venv for more information.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.

Please answer this, I install all the pre-requisite packages for python then also it is showing such error.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+error%3A+externally-managed-environment

You might prefer to install it via Anaconda, especially if you're new to Python. It includes a bunch of other scientific computing tools for Python.
